# Cassandra nodetool: Failed to connect to '127.0.0.1:7199'

Tags: java, ubuntu, cassandra, ubuntu-16.04, cassandra-3.0

I'm newbie in Cassandra apache. I install Cassandra on my VM

## cassandra: 3.11.2

## Ubuntu:16.04

## Java version "1.8.0_161"

● cassandra.service - LSB: distributed storage system for structured data Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/cassandra; bad; vendor preset: enabled) Active: active (exited).

After I nodetool status, it shows :

> Failed to connect to '127.0.0.1:7199' - ConnectException: 'Connection
>   refused (Connection refused)'.

I have tried

```
1.$JVM_OPTS -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1 in cassandra-env.sh
2.Set listen_address and broadcast_rpc_address to local ip in in cassandra.yaml
3.Restart Cassandra
```

It's still useless....

Comment: Are you sure Cassandra is running?

Comment: @Aaron It shows:
● cassandra.service - LSB: distributed storage system for structured data
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/cassandra; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited)..............so it's running right?

Comment: set $JVM_OPTS -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1/7199 in cassandra-env.sh

Answer (score 1):

Sheng, in your comment you say the service statement says:

"active (exited)"

That means the service is not running. I would check your log files "/var/log/cassandra/system.log" to see what is preventing C* from starting.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting seed address to your local IP in cassandra.yaml file and restart cassandra

Answer (score 0):

as your log -> `Active: active (exited).`
another reason for this problem occurred!
please get the log in debug.log and system.log for more!

Answer (score 0):

You have hit a known problem with the version of Java you're using.

```
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-14173 (Open; Unresolved; 3.11.2): "JDK 8u161 breaks JMX integration"
```